# Adobe Air native extension - drawable resources are packaged into APK but values resources are not

Tags: air, resources, adobe, native

I have a multiplatform Adobe Air Native Extension (ANE) that I have created.  The Android portion of the ANE includes resources (i.e. res/drawable, res/drawable-hdpi, res/layout, res/values).

When I create the ANE, the resources are included in the ANE properly.
(I have determined this by pulling apart the ANE and I see all my resources in the proper directories)

However, when I create the APK, it includes all my resources EXCEPT the res/values directory.
That whole directory and it's resources are not included.
(I have determined this by pulling apart the APK and looking at the res directory)

Does anyone know if there is something special in Adobe packaging of APK's that prevents res/values folder from ANE's being included in the final APK?

Answer (score 0):

What is happening in this situation is that the resources are being compiled into a binary format (in the resources.arsc file) so the original source files are not packaged into the APK.

If you dump the resources in the apk using aapt you can see that the resources are there:

```
 aapt dump --values resources your_app.apk
```